# get clicked link-button ID where all buttons already bind to one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

the app receive a n html dive and create a page and append it to the app

I bind all link-buttons in set of pages to one function
which will do different tasks depends on the id of the page
now I have a problem when a page has more than one link-button
I need the ID of the clicked button

Html:

```
<a id="x">x </a>
<a id="y">y </a>
```

Js:

```
   var btns = [];
   $('#page-' + newpages[j].pageID + ' a').each(function () {
       btns.push({
           id: this.id,
           value: this.value,
           name: this.name
       });
   });
   for (i in btns) {

       $('#' + btns[i].id).bind('click', function () {
           test(btns[i].id)
       });
       // bin all buttons in current page to test()
   }
};
};

function test(x) {
   var page = $('.ui-page-active').attr('id');

   /////////
   //here I'm trying to ge the ID of clicked button of that page (each ID means something)
   var pos = '';
   $('#' + page + ' a').click(function () {
       //Get the id of this clicked item

       var BID = $(this).attr("id");
       alert(BID);
       send(BID);
   });
```

Comment: Code like this should be banned from the Internet

Comment: It would be easier to help if u provide a js fiddle

Comment: You have a problem... right What is the Problem?

Comment: I can not get the ID of clicked button

Comment: @user2090426 In the click function, `this` corresponds to the element that was clicked. Thus, you can get the `id` of that element simply by doing `this.id`...

Comment: Are you missing `var BID;`...? Or is it a global one declared somewhere else..?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just bind to the click event on each button independently? If you switch by ID anyway why go through a generic function, any shared functionality can be abstracted into a function and utilized by each click handler so you loose nothing.

Comment: the buttons are dynamicaly created so I can not bind them before

Comment: Oh right ok, I guess you could subscribe to an event that fires when a new button is created to trigger the bindings again. It's not great, but I'd be tempted to do that rather than use a single function for all a tags. It's a tough one.